# Virtual box auto keyboard capture in win 10

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard

I am having an issue with Virtualbox.  I am trying to install a VM in Win 10 I am getting the Auto capture warning. Whenever I hover over the VM window my mouse curser disappears. I hit F1 I get it back but I cannot proceed with the install in the VM. I have unchecked the auto capture box in input preferences keyboard & double checked that it stays unchecked but as soon as my curser hovers back over this window its gone again. I am on a surface pro 3 tablet. I am running VB 6.04 ON WIN 10 1809 build. At a loss to what to do next. I have completely uninstalled VB reinstalled addeded expansion pack. same issue. I have a second pc HP laptop also running win 10 when loading the exact same iso image it works flawlessly. I am at my wits end on this as I have gone through all the forums & the consensus is make sure that auto capture box is unchecked which it has been. Any help or direction that can be given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which ISO are you trying to install?

Comment: Linux Mint 19.1. I also have two other VM instances as VDI files that were previously on this Pro 3 before the 1809 upgrade they have the same issue. I have verified the iso file & use the same iso on a seperate system & it works so corruption doesnt seem to be the issue.